# Can a F-1 visa holder teach an online course

Tags: usa, student-visa, working, non-residents

I was wondering if a F1 student can teach an online course in the University they are attached to. Usually, all F1 students working as TAs are assigned only face to face courses to teach but there are online courses offered by the universities which could be taught by a TA grad student. I was wondering if this is prohibited under the law if special permission is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F1 students are allowed to teach online courses in the University they are attached to (i.e., the I-20 issuing institution) if they follow the same paperwork and regulations as for offline courses (e.g., permitted up to 20 hours per week during the school year and more than 20 hours when school is not in session). Source: I was a non-American student  in the US and some of my labmates taught edX courses.